# Как открыть устройство?

Tags: c, com-порт

Есть Momentics, **работающий** в виртуальной **Windows XP** и **запускающий** программы в виртуальной же **QNX**. И есть некое устройство, подсоединенное к системе через COM-порт. Нужно открыть это устройство и отправить туда сообщение, в ответ оно отправит соответствующее сообщение (по протоколу). Как осуществить этот обмен или где можно об этом почитать?

Answer (score 1):

Всё взаимодействие между виртуальной машиной и реальным оборудованием типа COM-порта обслуживается соответствующим софтом для виртуализации. VMWare, VirtualBox или что там у вас установлено. Если прокидывание настроено должным образом, то работа с портом в виртуальной машине не должна ничем отличаться от оной в реальной.

Comment: Я, наверное, неправильно акцент поставил. Тут сама виртуальная машина значения не имеет, важно то, что C-программа запускается в QNX. Проблем с подключением нет, мне нужно именно открыть устройство, отправить на него сообщение и получить ответное.

Comment: @ratava `fd = open("/dev/ser1" ...); ... write(fd, ...); read(fd, ...);`

Comment: @alexolut, для последовательных портов надо ещё почитать про TERMIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Как выше отметили, нужно будет сначала настроить Ваш последовательный порт через termios. 
Например:

```
/*!*********************************************************************
 *  \brief  Функция по дескриптору файла устройства последовательного порта
 *           считыват структуру с текущей конфигурацией устройства,
 *           после чего устанавливаются параметры необходимые для обмена
 *           данными в неканоническом режиме
 *
 *  \param [in]     fd      Файловый дескриптор файла устройства "serial port"
 *  \param [in]     speed   Скорость порта (см. разрешенные значения в исходном коде)
 *
 *  \retval         0  - при успешном завершении;
 *  \retval         -1 - при ошибке, выводится сообщение об ошибке;
 ***********************************************************************/
int set_uart_attr(
    int fd,
    int speed
    )
{
    struct termios tty;

    /* получим текущую структуру терминального устройства */
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        perror("tcgetattr");
        return -1;
    }
    /* 
     * установим скорости ввода/вывода
     * Список стандартных скоростей:
     *      B0
     *      B50
     *      B75
     *      B110
     *      B134
     *      B150
     *      B200
     *      B300
     *      B600
     *      B1200
     *      B1800
     *      B2400
     *      B4800
     *      B9600
     *      B19200
     *      B38400
     *      B57600
     *      B115200
     *      B230400
     */
    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    /* активировать приемник, игнорировать управляющие линии модема*/
    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    /* очистить поле установки размера слова */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    /* установить размер слова (CS5 || CS6 || CS7 || CS8) */
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    /* отключить бит четности */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    /* использовать 1 стоп-бит вместо 2-х */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    /* запретить аппаратное управление потоком (RTS/CTS) */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    /* магия устанавливающая не канонический режим работы терминала */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON   );
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO   | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG   | IEXTEN                         );
    tty.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST                                                              );

    /**************************************************************************
     * В неканоническом режиме поля c_cc[VMIN] и c_cc[VTIME] задают условия 
     * возврата вызова "read()":
     * MIN == 0, TIME == 0 (чтение опросом (polling read))
     *        Если данные доступны, то read(2) завершает выполнение сразу, 
     *        возвращая меньшее или запрошенное количество байт. Если данных нет,
     *        то возвращает 0.
     * MIN > 0, TIME == 0 (блокирующее чтение)
     *        Вызов read(2) блокирует выполнение, пока не будет доступно MIN байт,
     *        и возвращает не более количества запрашиваемых байт.
     * MIN == 0, TIME > 0 (чтение с блокировкой по времени (read with timeout))
     *        В  TIME  указывается  время срабатывания таймера в десятых долях секунды. 
     *        Таймер запускается при вызове read. Завершается, когда не менее одного байта 
     *        станет доступно, или по таймеру. Если возврат произошел по таймеру,а данных
     *        не появилось, то возвращается 0. Если на момент вызова данные уже были,
     *        то они будут возвращены как будто были считанны при вызове.
     * MIN > 0, TIME > 0 (чтение с блокировкой по времени между байтами)
     *        В TIME указывается время срабатывания таймера в десятых долях секунды.
     *        После того, как первый байт станет доступен, таймер перезапускается 
     *        после каждого полученного байта.  Вызов read возвращает результат после
     *        удовлетворения любого из следующих условий:
     *        *  Было получено MIN байт.
     *        *  Истекло время межбайтового таймера.
     *        *  Получено запрошенное read количество байт
     *        Так как таймер запускается только после приёма начального байта, 
     *        будет прочитан, как минимум, один байт. Если на момент вызова read 
     *        данные уже были, то будут возвращены эти данные как будто они 
     *        поступили после вызова.
     *  (см. man termios(3) )
     *************************************************************************/
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    /* 
     * запишем измененную структуру обратно. Флаг "TCSANOW" означает
     * что изменения должны быть обработаны немедленно.
     */
    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```